# Batch kill all processes except non essential and cmd

Tags: batch-file, process, batch-processing

I am trying to make a batch file and part of it ends all none essential processes except cmd and chrome. So far i have:

```
cd c:\windows\System32
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="fun.bat" (
if not "%%i"=="mine.vbs" (
if not "%%i"=="chrome.exe" (
taskkill /f /im "%%i" 
))))))))
```

(taken from http://agnipulse.com/2009/02/kill-all-running-apps-with-a-double-click/ then eddited slightly)

and all of this works except the `if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (` 
for some reason the terminal exits even though it shouldn't.
Can anyone say why and how to fix it or a different way of ending all non essential processes?

edit: Also if i add a `pause`  to the end it never gets to that so i am now thinking that it program is killing its own process before it finishes the rest of the program even though `cmd.exe` is on the exception list. anyone think this could be the problem and any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You are missing /d in cd c:\windows\system32. The way you have it,  it will just use th directory the cmd prompt is at. Use cd /d c:\windows\system32 and see if it helps.

Comment: tried it no difference still  exits the terminal

Comment: Check the `TASKLIST ...` output carefully. I can see `explorer.exe` here. Killing it kills the windows shell. Start  `explorer.exe` at the end of your script.

Comment: Assuming that you meant can't its not supposed to be there but even when i add it the terminal still closes.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the answer to your question is that the terminal exits because you are double-clicking the batch file.  Whether you want it or not, this is expected behavior.  The action associated with double-clicking (as defined in the registry) is usually `cmd /c script.bat`.  The `/c` switch runs the command then exits.  If you want to keep the double-click-activated console alive after all other tasks are killed, add a `pause` at the end, or maybe add a wrapper at the top of the script with `cmd /k`, something like this:

```js
set "caller=%cmdcmdline:"=%"
if /I "%caller:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" (
    cmd /k "%~f0"
    goto :EOF
)
```

I see a couple of other issues as well.  You're searching your task list for a `.bat` script and a `.vbs` file.  Those aren't executables.  The processes parsing them will be `cmd.exe` and `cscript.exe`, respectively.

I suggest a different direction.  What would you think, instead of whitelisting executables, you whitelist *publishers* instead?  In this example, I whitelist Microsoft, Mozilla, Kingsoft (my virus scanner), Nvidia (audio, video, LAN, etc. driver helpers), and Google; and kill procs from other publishers.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "whitelist=Microsoft Google Mozilla Kingsoft Nvidia"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process get executablepath^,status /format:csv ^| find "\"'
) do (
    set "proc=%%~I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    set /p "=%%~I: "<NUL
    wmic datafile where "name='!proc:\=\\!'" get manufacturer | findstr /i "%whitelist%" >NUL && (
        echo OK
    ) || (
        echo UNACCEPTABLE!
        taskkill /im "%%~nxI" /f
    )
    endlocal
)
```

This way, any critical processes you might've forgotten to include, such as explorer.exe, won't be killed because they're published by Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry i probably could have phrased my question better but that was only part of my code earlier on it opens a second batch program that runs in a constant loop and it is this second 1 that exits when i don't want it to. I was also thinking that the program might end itself before it finnishes ending others?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to kill conhost.exe. It hosts the shell. On linux, conhost is bash, and cmd is gnome-terminal. So exclude conhost too. Also, if you are giving this to someone who have not the english QWERTY keyboard layout, add ctfmon.exe.